# Does a linter that ensures the object is not undefined when accessing its properties exist?

Tags: javascript, eslint, husky

I'm looking for a linter that can find errors caused by not checking if object(s) exist before accessing its properties, and the 'sub'-properties.

E.g. it should raise an error for this code

`const x = foo.prop`

Where it should be

`const x = foo && foo.prop`

A nice bonus would be raising an error in a case like this

`const x = foo && foo.prop.prop2` where the object itself is checked, but all properties might not be.

Any way of doing this is fine - be it an eslint plugin, pre-commit hooks via husky or similar.

Using `?.` notation is not currently an option for us as we still need to support some browsers without this feature.

We've looked for any way of doing this, and it seems this only exists on typescript as an eslint rule, and not JS. We haven't been able to find any existing eslint plugins on npm or similar that does this either.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a type checking system like TypeScript or Flow.

Comment: It would solve some issues for sure, but converting our entire codebase isn't really viable at this moment

Comment: Well, TS can also be configured to scan and warn of problems in purely JS files. In which case it will use JSDoc comments (if present) for type information or it will attempt to infer types from usage the best it can. So, for example `foo = (a, b) => a * b` will show an error when called as `foo("six", "nine")` because it seems to expect numbers.

Comment: This is not possible with a linter - how would it know that `foo` can be `undefined` and it needs to warn about this property access, but not about others?

Comment: @Bergi Any time an object property is accessed, without a previous && check? Is this not possible?

Comment: @ctpet Possible but pointless. Search your real code for the property access operator `.`: there's many more occurrences where you are accessing a method or something where a check is unnecessary. `Array.isArray()` for example? Also, your proposed "previous check" is futile: it only leads to more variables becoming `undefined`/`null` that you never expected to hold that value. At some point, you need to throw an error that something is wrong, and this should happen rather sooner than later.

Comment: Just to illustrate one of the pitfalls Bergi mentions: consider this code: `const a = 123; const b = a && a.toString(); const c = b && b.split(""); const d = c && c.slice(0, -1); const e = d && d.join(""); const f = e && Number(e);` It takes a number and removes the last digit from it. It's a bit naive but it's to showcase how much redundant code such a rule generates. And *real* code might be doing similar things where you assign part of the operation to a variable multiple times. Also consider that it's "safe* if `a` was `null` but if you did want a number at the end, it's useless being safe

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend TypeScript for this.

You mentioned that converting your entire codebase isn't an option, but you can selectively convert specific files and adjust as you go.

Just use .ts on the file that you require ts linting on and adjust eventual Webpack configurations to use `ts-loader` for `.ts` files, and you can go file by file (or keep it to that one file).

> Using ?. notation is not currently an option for us as we still need
> to support some browsers without this feature.

You can transpile these with Babel. You write:

```
foo?.bar;
```

Transpiled version:

```
foo == null ? void 0 : foo.bar;
```

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining